# Ember link-to params is empty in model function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following map

**Routes map**

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', {path: "/"}, function () {
        this.resource('project', {path: "/project/:id"}, function () {
            this.resource('settings'); 
        });
    });
});
```

**Loading models**

I'm using Ember Data to load models:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('project');
    }
});

App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    display_name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('project', params.id)
    }
});

App.Settings = DS.Model.extend({
    category: DS.attr(),
    /* bunch of properties */
    project: DS.belongsTo('project')
});

App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find('settings', params.id);
    }
});
```

**Templates**

And let's say we have the following template for project:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="project">
    <div class="sidebar">
        {{#link-to 'settings' id}}Settings{{/link-to}}
    </div>
    <div class="editor">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
```

The params argument of the model function in SettingsRoute is always empty. `params.id` in `return this.store.find('settings', params.id);` is `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My issue was that I'm using the term 'settings' and ember assumes that settings is not a singleton. I think these types of assumptions are really unusual in frameworks and Ember should force the developer to take care of that.

Comment: Where are you expecting the `id` in `{{#link-to 'settings' id}}` to be coming from?

Comment: It should be the id of the project: ```{ project: { id: '123qwe', ... } }```. ```{{id}}``` renders fine in the template. Please advise if the approach I'm following can be improved.

Comment: pass project object in link-to {{#link-to 'settings' project}} and in model hook of settings use params.project.id

Comment: Tried that, params is still empty.